# SQL Distinct based on different colum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem to distinct values on column based on other column. The case study is:

Table: List

```
well | wbore | op|
------------------
wella|wbore_a|op_a|
wella|wbore_a|op_b|
wella|wbore_a|op_b|
wella|wbore_b|op_c|
wella|wbore_b|op_c|
wellb|wbore_g|op_t|
wellb|wbore_g|op_t|
wellb|wbore_h|op_k|
```

So, I want the output to be appear in different field/column like:

```
 well | total_wbore | total_op
    ----------------------------
  wella |      2      |   3
    ---------------------------
  wellb |      2      |   2
```

the real study case come from different table but to simplify it I just assume this case happened in 1 table.

The sql query that I tried:

```
SELECT well.well_name, wellbore.wellbore_name, operation.operation_name, COUNT(*) 
FROM well
INNER JOIN wellbore ON wellbore.well_uid = well.well_uid
INNER JOIN operation ON wellbore.well_uid = operation.well_uid 
GROUP BY  well.well_name,wellbore.wellbore_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But this query is to calculate the duplicate row which not meet the requirement. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `count distinct`

```
SELECT 
  count(distinct wellbore.wellbore_name) as total_wbore
  count(distinct operation.operation_name) as total_op
FROM well
  INNER JOIN wellbore ON wellbore.well_uid = well.well_uid
  INNER JOIN operation ON wellbore.well_uid = operation.well_uid
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro... this solved my problem. I've spent hours on the query.

Comment: Glad to help @AriffKmy, in answer is correct could you please mark it as valid answer?

Answer (score -1):

Final query:

```
SELECT 
  well.well_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT wellbore.wellbore_name) AS total_wbore,
  COUNT(DISTINCT operation.operation_name) AS total_op
FROM well
  INNER JOIN wellbore ON wellbore.well_uid = well.well_uid
  INNER JOIN operation ON wellbore.well_uid = operation.well_uid
  GROUP BY well.well_name
```